# Circular button being displayed as a rectangle in a gridlayout

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display many circular buttons using a recycler view with a gridlayout. However, when I run the application on my emulator the buttons show up as squares. I noticed that when I look at the design view of my button layout file, the constraint layout that stores the button has a transparent rectangle surrounding the button. I'm not sure if my program is automatically filling the constraintview background as well along with the button, but I just wanted to let you know. Here is my onbindviewholder method in my recyclerview that fills the color of my buttons (colorResources is an array within my recycler view that holds the colors I want to fill my button with):

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(colorResources[position]));
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pickedColor=colorResources[position];
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my button xml file that is displayed in my recyclerview/gridlayout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="20dp">
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/button_color_background"
    android:id="@+id/colorButton" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the background xml file for my button referred to in the code above:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="999dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/purple_700"/>
    <stroke android:width="50px" android:color="#636161"/>
</shape>
```

Please let me know if you need any additional information about my code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just set width and height of your Button: Like:

```
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Shape should be oval.Use this as drawable instead.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#636161"/>
    <solid
        android:color="@color/purple_700"/>
</shape>
```

as long as button is a square this drawable will result in a circle. also you can increase the width in stroke according to your needs.